# How to show equivalence between two linear programs?

Tags: proof-verification, linear-programming

I'm looking to prove that this two programs are equivalent :

$\mathcal Min$ $Z$ $ax_1$+$bx_2$+$cx_3$

s.t.  $6x_1$-$x_2$+$3x_3$$\leq8$

$6x_1$-$x_2$+$3x_3$$\geq5$

$x_1$,$x_2$,$x_3$$\geq$0

and this :

$\mathcal Min$ $Z$ $ax_1$+$bx_2$+$cx_3$

s.t. $6x_1$-$x_2$+$3x_3$+$x_4$=8

$x_4$$\leq$3

$x_1$,$x_2$,$x_3$,$x_4$$\geq$0

I mean I can see that after introducing slack variables and subtracting the first equation from the second you get something close to what I want to prove but it's still unclear to me can you guys help me solve this please.

Comment: The boundary case $6x_1 - x_2 + 3 x_3 = 8$ is allowed in the first program, but not the second (since $x_4 > 0$ rather than $x_4 \geq 0$).

Comment: I'm sorry I made a mistake it's $\geq $ for both positivity constraints. but still I didn't understand what you said? can you clarify please ?

Comment: Had you restricted to the case $x_4 > 0$ as originally written, then possible set of values $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ with $6x_1 - x_2 + 3x_3 = 8$ would have been "allowable" values for the first case, but not for the second since if $6x_1 -x_2 + 3x_3 = 8$ and $x_4 > 0$, then $6x_1 - x_2 + 3x_3 = 8 - x_4 < 8$.

Comment: Cool I get it now thanks, but in my case I have all variables $\geq0$ what should change ? and can you tell me if the solution I thought about is correct or not (the subtraction of both equations) thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Show that the sets
$$
S = \{(x_1, x_2, x_3) \mid 5 \leq 6x_1 - x_2 + 3x_3 \leq 8, \,x_i \geq 0\}
$$
and 
$$
T = \{(x_1, x_2, x_3) \mid 6x_1 - x_2 + 3x_3 = 8 - x_4, \, x_i \geq 0, \, x_4 \leq 3\}
$$
are equal. (This is fairly clear when you realize $5 \leq 8-x_4 \leq 8$ when $0 \leq x_4 \leq 3$).

Comment: Thanks tom I just realised I messed up just did it thanks for your help !!